# How to get the full product name by ignoring custom modification on it

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, filters, title

I've added a filter to simplify product name on my shop page.
This is the code I use

```
add_filter('the_title', 'mod_product__title', 10, 2);
function mod_product__title($title, $id) {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( $pagenow != 'edit.php' && get_post_type( $id ) == 'product' ) {
        if(preg_match('/[^(:|.)]*/', $title, $matches)){
            return trim($matches[0]);
        }else{
            return $title;
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
```

As you can see here on the home page https://www.librairiedesarchives.com/
If you click on "Keith Sonnier" you will see his full product name only on the product page.

**Problem is** : when I use a button to share the page by mail (contact button on the product page), the name of the page is the one simplified by the previous custom code.

Currently, I use this code to get the name of the page on the email

```
add_shortcode( 'custom_mailto_title', 'custom_mailto_title' );

function custom_mailto_title( $atts ) {
    return esc_attr( get_the_title( get_the_ID() ) );
}
```

**How Can I** get the full name of the page with this button while keeping the product title simplified on the shop page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also get the title this way and avoid filters:

```
$title = get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id, 'raw' );
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you just tell me where do I have tu put this line? Do I have to edit the function for the shortcode?

Comment: Ok it seems to work with 
function custom_mailto_title( $atts ) {
    return esc_attr( get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id, 'raw') );
}


Thanks a lot :)